# jQuery radio buttons with toggle/remove class mystery

Tags: jquery, class, radio-button, switch-statement

There's something wrong with jQuery but I don't know why.

I've got three divs acting like radio buttons. First div has class "on", others have class "off". If I click on class "off" it changes to "on" but this doesn't work with the first div since I can't turn it back to "on". It works only if he has class "off" from the beginning. Can you tell me where's the problem?

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-radio-buttons">
                    <div class="on"></div>
                    <div class="off"></div>
                    <div class="off"></div>
                </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".off").click(function() {
    $(".on").removeClass('on').toggleClass('off');
    $(this).toggleClass('on').removeClass('off');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the first div had the class 'on' when `$('.off').click` was called. So, jQuery did not bind the event to to it.

You can bind the event as:

```
$(".slider-radio-buttons").on('click', '.off', function() {
    $(".on").removeClass('on').toggleClass('off');
    $(this).toggleClass('on').removeClass('off');
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/5/

Comment: +1 for a) getting in first and b) using the deferred `on` for event handling.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I think my answer (which was also first, we answered at the same time) is slightly better, as I optimized the code using cached variables.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Code Maverick: Andre's post was 19 seconds earlier (hover on the `"answered ... ago"` text to get exact time). As for optimization: "do not optimize unless it matters". This feature only has to operate at user click speed, so any speed difference is a non-issue :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - You never know when optimization matters until it matters, therefore you should always optimize your code.  Not caching variables is just a bad practice in general.

Comment: @Code Maverick: I agree it *can* be optimised (JQuery selectors have a lot to answer for, time-wise), but as for *when* it matters, the clue here was in "click". I had up-voted your answer already too for better reasons :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I understand with respect to this specific example. However, you never know what all else is going on in the page's code.  So in not optimizing it, you could just be adding to a mess that's already there.  To that point, I always try to provide the most efficient answer.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: In answer to the concerns of performance (vs. simplicity/readbility) I have added my own answer that is shorter, faster *and* simpler... I await your up-votes (but will not hold my breath) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks, fixed. English is not my native language.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Although I agree my code could be improved, just setting to a variable is actually a trade of memory for execution speed, as the`$buttons` variable in your example will not be garbaged collected. In this sense, I could argue that my code is actually more optimized than yours, in term of memory usage. Since there are different ways a code can be optimized, I tend to not optimize my code samples in SO unless the OP explicitly asks so.

Comment: @Andre - Take a look at the jsPerf tests I ran (posted in my answer).  Faster page execution is of greater importance to a user than minimal memory usage.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Now you are making assumptions about in what environment the OP will run the code in. Might be in a low-memory mobile devices, where memory usage is more important. Plus, I've just run your perfTests, and the results seems browser-dependent. Mine runs faster in Opera, which happens to be my browser of choice.

Comment: @Andre - Of course the results are browser dependent.  That's why I ran it on all the browsers that I currently have.   I was simply pointing out that caching variables is a better practice than to not cache.  And I think the results show that that is the case when you compare the results across all browsers tested.  Your answer is totally right, as are the others.  It's fun to see all the different ways people accomplish the same task and then compare results.

Comment: @CodeMaverick If you cache too many things, you'll end up with a higher memory usage. Again, this is a trade-off, and whether this is good or bad is dependent on the environment the code will be run. Only the OP can answer this, and maybe not even him. Don't make such assumptions.

Comment: Another thing, if you cache in javascript variables, you may pollute global namespace, causing hard-to-track bugs, AND is a bad coding practice. An workaround for this is using closures, which may reduce code clarity. I would never, ever trade code clarity for a negligible performance gain.

Comment: I recommend you to read [Benchmarking Mistake #1](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one), by Eric Lippert. If you are interested in reading all blog posts, you can find all four [here](http://tech.pro/ericlippert/blog)

Comment: @Andre - I don't ever work in global.  I use [markup-based unobtrusive comprehensive DOM-ready execution](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) championed by Paul Irish.

Comment: @CodeMaverick: I have exhausted my arguments on performance, so will end with this simple question: *"Can you click your mouse 90,000 times per second?"*... :)

Answer (score 2):

As there has been some (lengthy) discussion regarding optimisation of code (that is only used at user interface speeds) I would counter-propose than the following is both faster *and* simpler:

### http://jsfiddle.net/TGc7L/2/

```
$("div.slider-radio-buttons div").on("click", function () 
{
    $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on").addClass("off");
});
```

The selector is only used once. All other access is either to the known target element (with `$(this)`), or to the siblings of that element, which could (I believe) be accessed faster with `siblings()`.

### http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-siblings/3

[image]
*Note: being ever dubious of statistics, I made the perf tests into a fair comparison by excluding the initial jQuery selector. It appears that using `siblings()` is a fraction faster than iterating a JQuery collection (in Chrome), and about the same speed on other browsers, which is handy to know.

My original point was basically "not to worry about speed in user interface interactions, unless there is a problem". I would use the above technique anyway as it is simpler to read/maintain. Just how fast can you click the mouse? certainly not 90,000 times a second :)

Comment: +1 for the alternate attempt.  However, to me, it seems that this would be slower due to the fact that you would be calling `siblings()` on every click vs the method I had which caches all the divs up front and only does so once.

Comment: @Code Maverick: now you are jumping to conclusions... siblings "could" operate faster as it can traverse the DOM laterally (as the DOM is already linked between siblings). Again we are arguing at the bleeding edge of speed when we are dependant on JQuery code written by others. I would prefer this on simplicity alone, but I look forward to your performance timing results :)

Comment: I decided to run a [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-siblings).  They are very close and almost exact in Chrome and Firefox.  Mine is slightly faster in IE.

Comment: @Code Maverick: As they are so close, speed-wise, and it only gets executed once per mouse click (5 times per second max?) I think I have made my point. Having maintained other people's JQuery code I always prefer readability, maintainability and simplicity *except when speed is an actual issue* :)

Comment: Acutally, I had set up the test wrong.  I was supposed to put my cached variable in the setup area, not in the test case.  With that done, mine is fastest across the board.  I also included the non-cached accepted answer and it came in second, with yours coming in last.

Comment: @Code Maverick: *Lies, darn lies, statistics and now perftests...* The other 2 examples use deferred ON, so it is not possible to equate them that way as only the event code gets run multiple times. Nice bit of creative accounting though :)

Comment: All I ever try to do here on SO is give thorough, optimized, correct answers vs answering first just so I can get votes simply for answering first. The answers that I see doing that tend to almost always end up not taking into account best coding practices and usually are just copy/paste/slight modify of the OPs original code.  I originally was just trying to point out that my answer was just as deserving of an upvote, if not more so, due to it being optimized.  I didn't know that I was going to have to jsPerf it just to validate my reasoning.

Comment: @Code Maverick: Your perf tests were not testing the actual code, but mainly the JQuery selectors (which is incorrect). If you use a predefined selector in both test yours is second-fastest by around 1%, so it appears sibling access is faster than iterating a JQuery collection (which is good to know).

Comment: @CodeMaverick Not every answer in SO is about providing production quality code. Providing an answer that is closer to OP original code makes easier to point where the code is wrong, which may be enough for him/her.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Yours was slightly faster in Chrome, but mine was faster in Firefox and IE if you were using http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-siblings/3.

Comment: @CodeMaverick: Chrome now has the greatest market share, so I'm happy with that... but I still can't click my mouse fast enough to care about the differences :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".off, .on").click(function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass('off'))
    {
        $(".on").toggleClass('on off');
        $(this).toggleClass('on off');       
    }

});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UyKzf/7/

**Edit for later viewer :**

**[usefull]** This answer was not very good because of ( see TrueBlueAussie comment )

Comment: ^^ You have a lot a answers, just need to choose which answer accept, hard job...

Comment: Andre As better answer because as TrueBlueAussie says, he use 'on' . I'll choose this one too.

Comment: @Jahnux73: Your `if` statement is unnecessary if one element is already in the `on` state. Having a dependency on the initial state at all though is more prone to bugs (and so not recommended). Better to explicitly remove/add than toggle all elements' states.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'm ok with you, but this aspect was not introduce in question (but it's not a reason I accord it ^^)

Comment: @Jahnux73: In that case, I simply state "Your if statement is unnecessary" (for the question asked) :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is turn them all off and then simply turn the one on that was clicked.

### [See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TGc7L/)

---

### HTML

```
<div class="slider-radio-buttons">
    <div class="on">Choice 1</div>
    <div class="off">Choice 2</div>
    <div class="off">Choice 3</div>
</div>
```

---

### jQuery

```
var $buttons = $("div.slider-radio-buttons div");

$buttons.on("click", function () 
{
    $buttons.removeClass("on").addClass("off");
    $(this).removeClass("off").addClass("on");
});
```

---

### CSS

```
.off 
{
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: #FFE3B3;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.off:hover 
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.on 
{
    background: #FFA200;
}
```

---

Since there has been discussion on what answer is faster, or more efficient, I thought I'd run a performance test.  Cached vs Siblings vs Non-Cached.

### [See jsPerf test results](http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-siblings)

### [See jsPerf revision test results](http://jsperf.com/cached-vs-siblings/3)

Comment: Given our lengthy discussion (and my opinion that there is *always a better way to do things*) I have posted my own optimised version as well, for your review. cheers.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I've added the revision test results tested across 3 browsers instead of just one and mine is still the fastest overall.